# Javascript filtering images depending on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

i am trying to make certain images fade when i use a check box, the filter works by recognizing the check box being checked and fading the appropriate images leaving the one that is want

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

$("#filter-category£5-10").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr('checked'))
        $('.category£11-15bag').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    else
        $('.category£11-15bag').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.2);

});

$("#filter-category£11-15").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr('checked'))
        $('.category£5-10bag').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    else
        $('.category£5-10bag').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.2);

});
</script>
```

this is the style for the class i created:

```
.category£5-10bag{width:100px; height:100}
.category£11-15bag{width:100px; height:100}
```

these are the images with the class:

```
<img src="picture box image.png" style = "position:relative; top:-1050px; right:-42"  class="category£5-10bag"/>

<img src="picture box image.png" style = "position:relative; top:-1050px; right:-42"  class="category£11-15bag"/>
```

please tell me if you notice any problems, when i try and use it nothing happens at all

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your approach (mainly because I'm not wholly certain that `£` is a valid symbol to use in either a `class` or an `id`, and using the following approach:

#### html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="category" id="five-to-ten" />
<label for="five-to-ten">£5-10</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="category" id="eleven-to-fifteen" />
<label for="eleven-to-fifteen">£11-15</label>


<!-- the images are, of course, generic place-holders -->
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" data-price="five-to-ten" />    
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nightlife" data-price="eleven-to-fifteen" />
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('img').hide();
$('input.category').change(
    function(){
        var test = this.checked;
        $('img[data-price="' + this.id + '"]')[test ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qhJxk/).

This has some benefit, in that it's inherently more scalable, and doesn't require a new click-handler for *every* checkbox, it uses the `data-*` custom attributes to contain the price category (which is equal to the `id` attribute of the relevant check-box).

The use of the ternary operator (`test ? 'show' : 'hide'`) is used to call the `show()` or `hide()` methods depending on whether the check-box is checked, or not; and takes advantage of the fact that:

```
$(selector).hide()
```

can *also* be implemented using:

```
$(selector)['hide']();
```

References:

- [attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).